# Cannot display extra attributes in my query request

Tags: mysql

This is my little Salesman table I am working on:

```
+-------+--------------+--------+
| empId | name         | gender |
+-------+--------------+--------+
|     3 | Suresh Raina | M      |
|     5 | Andrew       | M      |
|     7 | Moeen        | F      |
|    11 | Moeen        | M      |
+-------+--------------+--------+
```

What I have to display in my query is the following:

```
name       count
Andrew       1
Moeen        2 (7,Moeen,F)(11,Moeen,M)
Suresh Raina 1
```

If count has more than one matching name then it displays all the attributes.

I have the following query but it is not printing the ones that have a count higher than 1.

```
select all  name, count( name) AS totalNumber 
  from Salesman GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name)= 1 OR COUNT(name)>1 IN 
   ( select group_concat(empId ,name , gender) from Salesman group by name ) order by name asc;
```

Any hints or ideas you can share would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

## Query

```
select
  name,
  count(*) as count,
  case when count(*) < 2 then ''
  else
  concat('(',
    group_concat(
      concat_ws(',', empid, name, gender)
      separator '),('
    ),
    ')'
  )
  end as flds
from salesman
group by name
```

## Result

> ```
> name         | count | flds                    
> :----------- | ----: | :-----------------------
> Andrew       |     1 |                         
> Moeen        |     2 | (7,Moeen,F),(11,Moeen,M)
> Suresh Raina |     1 |
> ```

## Example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9a804f0ac1a7290af61ce3649670358c

## Explanation

Start with this:

```
select name, count(*) as counter
from salesman
group by name
```

This gives you name and count. That's all good.

Now, you want to combine the fields. So, you could use `concat_ws`. The first parameter to that function will be the separator. We'll use `,`. Then will be the list of fields.

So, `concat_ws(',', name, gender)` will return `John,M` or whatever the name in each row is. We'll take advantage of that.

Since we want to use concat_ws along with count(*), we need to do some kind of summarization of concat_ws. We do that with group_concat.

```
select name, count(*) as counter, group_concat(concat_ws(',', empid, name, gender))
from salesman
group by name
```

gives us

> ```
> name         | counter | group_concat(concat_ws(',', empid, name, gender))
> :----------- | ------: | :------------------------------------------------
> Andrew       |       1 | 5,Andrew,M                                       
> Moeen        |       2 | 7,Moeen,F,11,Moeen,M                             
> Suresh Raina |       1 | 1,Suresh Raina,M
> ```

Alright, we are closer. Now, we give group_concat a separator. That separates the records. We use the separate `),(` so that the query becomes like this:

```
select name, count(*) as counter,
  group_concat(concat_ws(',', empid, name, gender) separator '),(')
from salesman
group by name
```

gives

```
> <pre>
> name         | counter | group_concat(concat_ws(',', empid, name, gender) separator '),(')
> :----------- | ------: | :----------------------------------------------------------------
> Andrew       |       1 | 5,Andrew,M                                                       
> Moeen        |       2 | 7,Moeen,F),(11,Moeen,M                                           
> Suresh Raina |       1 | 1,Suresh Raina,M                                                 
> </pre>
```

Even closer. All we have left is to add open and closed parenthesis around our group concat. Once we do that, we get a clean output.

However, we don't want Andrew and Suresh's information to be published because their count is 1. So, we put a `case when ... else ... end` statement.

Comment: Love the demo, and the step by step detailed explanation. This is how SO answerer should all strive for

Comment: This is what I did I believe I over complicated it and maybe left some vulnerabilities? select all  name, count( name) AS totalNumber, IF(count(name)>1 , group_concat("(",empId, ", "  , name, "," , gender,")") , " " )as " " from Salesman GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name)= 1 OR COUNT(name)>1 IN ( select group_concat(empId ,name , gender) from Salesman group by name ) order by name asc;

Comment: @manny you were really close. In fact, I took the solution you had in your question and built my answer upon it. You did a great job of providing clarity in your question.

Comment: Actually I appreciate all of your help this really helped me better understand the problem. Thank you!